# python : request dependency idna failed "ImportError: No module named idna"

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using the request module in python, which has inda as a dependency.

I am keeping idna module inside request module but still it is not able to detect the inda module.

"/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1522067995292_0020/container_1522067995292_0020_01_000001/slackclient.zip/slackclient/requests/packages.py", line 7, in 
ImportError: No module named idna

Comment: Have you used `pip install idna`?

Comment: correct i am installing using pip only.                                                                 one quick thing i would like to mention here it is working in my local python but when i am uploading the python dependency to aws glue then it is breaking.

Comment: Then you don't have `idna` in your requirements file for aws.

Comment: idna module is there inside requirement module on the basis of that only i am testing it.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and strangely installing idna worked for me

```
$ pip install idna
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `pip` isn't starting because of this very error for me (OpenSUSE 15.3).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But I was using anaconda due to that, pip command did not work for me, So I used the following command to resolve that.

```
conda install -c conda-forge idna
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `requirements.txt` avoid these dependency mix-ups.

Firstly, when your code is working all good, do this

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This stores all the installed packages into the text file.

Now use `requirements.txt` file to install all modules wherever it runs hereafter

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If needed, can upgrade your modules and check everything working cool and then update `requirements.txt` again.

When not mentioning the versions, usually the latest versions of the packages are fetched and installed. Some of the updates from dependency's dependency(inception) package might break.

Comment: This information would only help if the program is already running properly and doesn't solve the problem of the dependency issue.